# how to access asp listbox's checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, checkedlistbox

```
     if (lstbx_formname.Items[i].Enabled==true)
            {
                if (lstbx_formname.Items[i].Selected) 
                {
                    if (hh == "")
                    {
                        hh = "" + lstbx_formname.Items[i].Value + "";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        hh = hh + "," + lstbx_formname.Items[i].Value + "";
                    }
                }                             
            }
```

// i have listitems which are disabled and now while looping i want skip disabled and unchecked listitem
and get checked items in listbox

```
    if (lstbx_formname.Items[i].Enabled==true)
            {
                if (lstbx_formname.Items[i].Selected) 
                {
                    if (hh == "")
                    {
                        hh = "" + lstbx_formname.Items[i].Value + "";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        hh = hh + "," + lstbx_formname.Items[i].Value + "";
                    }
                }                             
            }
```

Comment: and what's your problem? Does the above code do what you want? And where is the difference between those two snippets?

Comment: and where is your loop?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: and listbox does not have check box, so this is even more confusing.